# What's a word for "causing conflict/inciting hostility/setting people up against another/enciting violence"

Tags: synonyms

I'm sure it's an easy word that's just trapped in the back of my mind somewhere, but google didn't help, so I hope you guys can.

When someone has been conniving and conspiring to meddle in the affairs of other people behind their backs, and set formerly friendly people or parties up to be hostile towards one another, then that person is... ?

"They were as suscpetible to his ___" (not '**meddling**', but specifically causing hostility and turning relations sour)

The closest candidates I can think of are '**pulling strings**' and '**shit stirring**'. Maybe the word could also be used to describe the action of a dog owner inciting his dog to go for another person or game.

Thanks for any help and all effort.

Comment: ***Instigating*** and synonyms.

Comment: Slakslak, you can post the answer (solution)  yourself. Mr. Bron won't mind at all. Isn't that so @DanBron?

Comment: I would still like to leave it open to other suggestions though. You never know what someone else might come up with.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @Mari-LouA.

Comment: The question remains open even if you post an answer. I also post answers to my questions when I can, and if I'm in the mood.

Comment: "**incitement**" actually works fine too. That's the legal term for instigating crimes/violence, as well. If you're looking for a word that would match the connotation of siccing a dog on someone, "**goading**" might be a good synonym.

Comment: Alright, answer's up, thanks. Never heard of goading or, more importantly, siccing before, but I'll take it. Thanks. What about solicit? I saw it as a translation to the German word. But I don't think I've seen it being used in the context of causing trouble.

Answer (score 3):

**Instigate**, **Incite/Incitement**, **goad** fit the purpose well.

Answer (score 2):

**Invidious** or maybe an *invidious interloper*,
or *invidious intent*.

[Google Dictionary definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=invidious&oq=invidious&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i433j0l5.4786j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You should add the definition to your answer in case the link ever goes dead and also explain why this fits the OPs request.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answers you have:

- Rile (rile up)
- Provoke
- Sedition (seditious)
- Inflame